# Using generics in Typescript and type inference

Tags: typescript, generics

In C# i have the following generic definitions.

```cs
public interface IMediator{
        TResult ExecuteQuery<TResult>(Query<TResult> query);
    }
public abstract class Query<TResult> { }
```

Using this is then 'easy' looking something like this.

```cs
public class MyQuery<MyResult> {
  public string SomeValue
}

//later in code
var res = mediator.ExecuteQuery(new MyQuery {SomeValue="Test"});

//The type of res will now be MyResult, infered from the Query
```

Is this possible to do in TypeScript? 
I tried to "copy" the solution but the type inference did not work as expceted.

```js
export interface IQuery<T> {}
export async function QueryServer<T>(query:IQuery<T>) : Promise<T> {
  return await fetch(.......).Json();
}

class TestQuery implements IQuery<string[]> {
    something: string;

    constructor(something: string) {
        this.something = something
    }
}

var res = await QueryServer(new TestQuery("BLABLA"));
```

The type of `res` is now `unknown` while developing..

Comment: What do you mean here by "as expected?" What code did you write that uses this? What did you expect to happen? What did happen?

Comment: Well.. When calling the function ```var res = await QueryServer(new TestQuery("BLABLA"));``` the type of res is ```unknown```

Comment: the function it self did actually work, but the inferring of the type while developing did not work

Comment: What is the definition of `IQuery`? What's the actual code here? Please post something we can put into typescriptlang.org/play, and see what you're seeing, along with what you expect to see.

Comment: What type do you expect `res` to be here? I can't find a set of types where this makes sense. Looking at it, TestQuery should implement `IQuery<string>`, not `IQuery<string[]>`, in which case all the types seem fine and are inferred. How does `IQuery` actually use `T`?

Comment: IQuery, does not use it actually, it's only usage is to tell the instansiator of the class what is the expected return type when calling through the  ```QueryServer``` method.

Comment: I don't believe that kind of usage is possible in TypeScript. TypeScript is structurally typed ("duck typed"). The only thing a type does provide an alias for a set of properties. If the type parameter isn't used, then it's not part of the type. (This is in contrast to C#, which is nominally typed. Two things with the same shape may not have the same type in C#, but they will in TypeScript.)

Comment: It's not clear exactly what problem you're trying to solve with this construct. You probably want to go back to a basic form without types, and then add types that solve specific problems. Types serve different purposes in TypeScript than in C#. Many C# patterns are unnecessary in TypeScript, so simply transliterating C# is often not going to be helpful (and may not even be possible).